# Celery: poll application state synchronously

Tags: python, celery

I wan't to retrieve my applications state, but currently I only have found out how to do this asynchronously using events.

```
>>> state = app.events.State()
>>> def on_event(event):
...     state.event(event)
... 
>>> with app.connection() as connection:
...     recv = app.events.Receiver(connection, handlers={'*': on_event})
...     recv.capture(limit=None, timeout=None, wakeup=True)
...
```

The `state` instance update every time an event occurs. But I want to synchronously create a snapshot from the current state. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a snapshot every n seconds, or you want to be able to make an on-the-fly call and fetch the state?

Comment: @MuMind: I want to make an on-the-fly call and fetch, as I don't want to be relying on a monitor process/thread.